# If $G$ is not complete, then $\kappa(G) \ge 2\delta(G) -n + 2$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. Show that if $G$ isn't complete, then $\kappa(G) \ge 2\delta(G) - n + 2$, where $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of the vertices of $G$, and $\kappa(G)$ is the connectivity of $G$.

Why is this true, if $G$ has only one vertex for example, then isn't $\kappa(G)= 0 < 2\cdot0 -1 + 2$, showing that the statement is false. Maybe this is just an edge case though. Still, I don't know how to approach this proof.

Comment: Could you please tell what $\kappa(G)$ and $\delta(G)$ are?

Comment: And, by the way, graph with one vertex is complete.

Comment: Oh shoot, ofc it is complete haha. Also edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to prove first, that if graph on $n$ vertices is disconnected, then $\delta(G) \leqslant \frac{n-2}{2}$.

So, suppose we deleted $k$ vertices and obtained disconnected graph $H$. Then $|H|=n-k$ and $\delta(H) \geqslant \delta(G)-k$. So

$$ \delta(G)-k \leqslant \frac{n-k-2}{2}. $$

After simple transformations, we arrive at thesis.